# Character sums over a fixed subset of skew tableaux

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

Let $f(\lambda)$ count the number standard young tableaux of shape $\lambda\vdash n$ and $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r)$. Let $\mu \vdash k$ be a partition for $k<n$. It is a consequence of the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule that:

$$\chi^{\lambda}_{(\mu,1^{n-|\mu|})}=\sum_{\alpha\vdash |\mu|}\chi_{\mu}^{\alpha}  f(\lambda\backslash \alpha),$$

where $\chi_\mu^\lambda$ is the irreducible character. This is invertible, giving:

$$f(\lambda\backslash \alpha) =\sum_{\mu\vdash k}\frac{\chi_\mu^\alpha}{z_\mu}\chi_{\mu 1^{n-|\mu|}},$$

where $z_\mu$ is the central character.

I'm trying to understand the nature of $f_m:=f(\lambda\backslash 1^{r-m})$ for $m=1,2,\cdots,r$. Obviously these can be computed by the Aitken determinent formula but I'm much more interested in them from a representation theory point of view. Specifically I'd like to consider restrictions of the above sum to just $f_m$. So for example, is there an interpretation for:

$$(?)=\sum_{m=1}^{\lambda_1}\chi_{\mu}^{\alpha}  f_m?$$

I'm not sure if it's wise to just fix $\mu$ here. Have such things been considered before?

Comment: The closest thing might be some sort of interpretation in terms of Shifted Schur functions, see (0.14) in http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9605042v1.pdf
after some suitable scaling (perhaps divide both sides with $f_\lambda$?).

Comment: It appears that the count of skew SYT of shape $\lambda / \alpha$ equals the count of SYT of all partitions generated in the decomposition of $s_{\lambda / \alpha}$ including LR-multiplicities. Can't prove it though.